# Compare 2 csv files and remove the common lines from 1st file | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I want to compare 2 csv files master.csv and exclude.csv and remove all the matching lines based on column1 and write the final output in mater.csv file.

**master.csv**

```
abc,xyz
cde,fgh
ijk,lmn
```

**exclude.csv**

```
###Exclude list###
cde
####
```

**Expected output (it should overwrite master.csv**

```
abc,xyz
ijk,lmn
```

**Tried till now**

```
with open('exclude.csv','r') as in_file, open('master.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set()
    for line in in_file:
        if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there should be some `pandas` or other modules approaches, but here is a pure pythonic approach:

```py
with open("master.csv") as f:
  master = f.read()
with open("exclude.csv") as f:
  exclude = f.read()

master = master.strip().split("\n")
exclude = exclude.strip().split("\n")

returnList = []
for line in master:
  check = True
  for exc in exclude:
    if exc in line:
      check = False
      break
  if check:
    returnList.append(line)

with open("master.csv", "w") as f:
  f.write("\n".join(returnList))
```

##### Output of master.csv

```
abc,xyz
ijk,lmn
```

Comment: Thanks @Amirhossein...It's works perfectly fine but how do I overwrite the master.csv file with the returned output.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer Thanks for the comment. I edited the answer as per your comment. Hopefully, it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Amirhossein...This is exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way by using pandas..

```
    import pandas as pd 
# Reading the csv file
df_new = pd.read_csv('Names.csv')
 
# saving xlsx file
GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('Names.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(GFG, index=False)
 
GFG.save()
```

Comment: there are 2 csv files here

Answer (score 0):

A purely pythonic answer leveraging list comprehensions:

```
with open('master.csv', 'r') as f:
    keep_lines = f.readlines()

with open('exclude.csv', 'r') as f:
    drop_lines = f.readlines()

write_lines = [line[0] for line in zip(keep_lines, drop_lines) if line[0].strip().split(',')[0] != line[1].strip()]

with open('master.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(write_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

master_df=pd.read_csv('master.csv')
exclude_df=pd.read_csv('exclude.csv')
conc=pd.concat([master_df,exclude_df])  #concatenate two dataframe
conc.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1'],inplace=True,keep=False)
print(conc)
```

drop_duplicates with subset = col1 will check for duplicate in col1 only

and keep has 3 values allowed:first,last and False...
i have chosen keep=False to not keep any duplicate

**Dataset:**

master.csv:

```
col1,col2
abc,xyz
cde,fgh
ijk,lmn
```

exclude.csv:

```
col1
cde
```